# Flutter : How to set fix width of Bar chart Column with scrolling x axis

Tags: flutter, bar-chart

flutter_charts: ^0.1.10

https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter

https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/BarChart-class.html

i Want set fix width of bar chart and need to scroll horizontal x axis.so it possible?

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

final data = [
      new OrdinalSales('2014', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2015', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2016', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2017', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2018', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2019', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2020', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2021', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2022', random.nextInt(100)),
      new OrdinalSales('2023', random.nextInt(100)),
    ];
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
    );
  }
...
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Or alternatively, a horizontalbarchar with a vertical scroll, would be nice to know.

Comment: Why not use your desired column width to calculate what the parent width should be? Wrap the chart with a `SizedBox`, wrapped with a horizontal  `SingleChildScrollView`. Set the width of the `SizedBox` to eg. `1.5 * desiredColumnWidth * columnCount`. I don't know the exact padding between the columns, but it visually seems to be about half a column width.

Comment: @Ovidiu, tested, and it works. Feel free to post your answer for the bounty.

Comment: have u found any solution??

Answer (score 5):

Why not use your desired column width to calculate what the parent width should be? Wrap the chart with a `SizedBox`, wrapped with a horizontal `SingleChildScrollView`. Set the width of the `SizedBox` to eg. `1.5 * desiredColumnWidth * columnCount`. I don't know the exact padding between the columns, but it visually seems to be about half a column width.

Comment: in your case, what is the desiredColumnWidth and column count value?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by setting an initial viewport and adding the `SlidingViewport` and `PanBehavior` to your chart:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final barsToDisplay = 3;

    return new charts.BarChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
        viewport: charts.DateTimeExtents(
          start: DateTime(data.first.year),
          end: DateTime(data[barsToDisplay - 1].year),
        ),
      ),
      behaviors: [
        // Adding this behavior will allow tapping a bar to center it in the viewport
        charts.SlidingViewport(
          charts.SelectionModelType.action,
        ),
        charts.PanBehavior(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: This code tells me that type 'DateTimeAxisSpec' is not a subtype of type 'AxisSpec<String>'. The BarChart constructor doesn't accept DateTime as a value, it only accepts String. How do you get around this?

Comment: Answered my own question by reviewing the example here:  https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/ordinal_initial_viewport.